# how does ng-controller directive create a new child scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was going through the ng-controller tutorial on angularjs.org website. I came across a scope inheritance example in http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/ . Here the author says the ng-controller directive creates a new child scope, i.e in the scope inheritance example we have 3 controllers and 4 scopes. Hows does this happen?. the code from the fiddle is below:

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('scopeInheritance', []);
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.timeOfDay = 'morning';
  $scope.name = 'Nikki';
}]);
myApp.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.name = 'Mattie';
}]);
myApp.controller('GrandChildCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.name = 'Gingerbreak Baby';
}]);
```

There is some problem with the fiddle link, so attaching rest of the code below:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="scopeInheritance">
  <div ng-app="scopeInheritance" class="spicy">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>

      <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
        <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>

        <div ng-controller="GrandChildCtrl">
          <p>Good {{timeOfDay}}, {{name}}!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle is empty :)

Comment: Every ng-app has a $rootScope, every ng-controller create new scope that has a prototype that is $rootScope or the scope above it in the DOM tree. That is why 3 controllers has 4 scopes (with one $rootScope).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to nest an app inside another app like that. Correct me if I'm wrong. I think that's an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the exact markup, it is difficult to tell, however, if each of these controllers is used once, then you would have 3 scopes + root scope.

When Angular encounters directives (built in or otherwise) that define themselves as needing a scope, then a new scope is created.  This is done in the `scope` property of the directive and you can find documentation about that [in the directive docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

`ng-controller` is a built-in Angular directive that requires a new inherited scope.  So, when Angular is compiling the DOM tree, it will create scopes for each controller.  So, that accounts for 3 of the 4 scopes.

There is also a *special* scope that `ng-app` directive defines called `$rootScope`.  The `$rootScope` is the top-level parent scope on the page.  So, this accounts for the fourth scope.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Makes sense now, didnt fully understand the explanation in the angular documentation. Thanks Davin.